# Alternate solution to get Result set of Stored Procedure without using reference cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Developer Version -4.0.2.15.21-x64. I am facing a problem to get result-set from a stored procedure.

Currently I am using reference cursor to get fetched data into result-set, but this approach leading me to a problem, as i have to add some extra java code for this functionality.

Is there any other approach to get result-set from stored procedure? If there, then please give me detailed solution of it

Current approach is:

```
/*creating reference cursor here  */

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE IC_FISCAL_VIEW_TEST(
   PARM_YEAR IN NUMBER, 
   PARM_PERIOD IN NUMBER, 
   P_CURSOR IN OUT types.cursorType)
IS
...
/* fetching data into resultset */
OPEN P_CURSOR FOR
SELECT  A.YEAR, A.PERIOD, A.MLTS_TYP, A.MEM_CATG_CDE, 
        A.MEM_CATG_CDE_DESC, A.AGRD_RATE,
```

Looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: In the IDE or. .? What problem? Please provide some context

Comment: not in IDE.. I am asking, how to get result set from stored procedure without using reference cursor

Comment: Current approach is: 

 /*creating reference cursor here  */

create or replace PROCEDURE IC_FISCAL_VIEW_TEST(PARM_YEAR IN 
NUMBER, PARM_PERIOD IN NUMBER,
PARM_MLTS IN VARCHAR2, PARM_PLAN_CDE IN VARCHAR2, PARM_MEM_CATG_CDE IN 
VARCHAR2, PARM_TYPE IN VARCHAR2, P_CURSOR IN OUT types.cursorType 
 )
IS


/* fatching data into resultset */
OPEN P_CURSOR FOR

SELECT  A.YEAR, A.PERIOD, A.MLTS_TYP, 
        A.MEM_CATG_CDE, 
        A.MEM_CATG_CDE_DESC, 
        A.AGRD_RATE,

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Is it a large data set or reasonable enough to return as XML , assuming XML is easier for you to handle. If so, loo at the Oracle XMLELEMENT/XMLATTRIBUTE/XMLAGG/XMLFORREST functions. You can return the resulting XML as an XMLTYPE or CLOB.

Comment: @TenG yes it's large data set. here i have just mention only the pattern i followed. thanks